# Printing selected dates using datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using datetime picker UI as follows:
https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-datetime-picker

The main part of the code for displaying the startdate, time and endate,time are :

```
<p class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
            <input type="text" class="dt_date_start"/>
            <input type="text" class="dt_time_start" /> .........TO............
            <input type="text" class="dt_date_end" />
            <input type="text" class="dt_time_end" />
        </p>
```

Now, I have a specific date range using the following code:

```
// Setting range for dates 
      $('.dt_date_start').datepicker({
        startDate: '-13d',
        endDate: '+0d',
    });

     $('.dt_date_end').datepicker({
        startDate: '-13d',
        endDate: '+0d'
    });
```

Now, I need to print two values : the selected start date and time (concatenated) and the selected end date and time (concatenated) in a format like below :
These selections are done by the user in the datetime picker

Fri Jun 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

This needs to be done, so I can filter my data according to these two values from the json file that I am loading in the backend.

I have tried these till now, but am unable to get a format like I need.

```
    var value = $("#myDate input").datepicker("getDate");


    $('#timeformatExample1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s' });
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.